# Align content to left of viewport vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm just getting started with Nuxt.js and Vuetify.js with a simple "Hello World". I expected the text to be left aligned to the viewport but instead it's offset. Decreasing the width of the window to 959px makes the text behave as planned so I imagine there's a breakpoint at work. But I can't find the code for that breakpoint. How do I get "Hello World" to go straight to the left

```
index.vue

<template>
 <div>
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
 </div>
</template>



<script>
export default {
    head () {
    return {
      title: 'Hello World',
      meta: [
        // hid is used as unique identifier. Do not use `vmid` for it as it will not work
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'My custom description' },
        { hid: 'keywords', name: 'keywords', content: 'My custom description' },
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Result 
[image]

Comment: There is padding for v-container, v-row and v-col, are you loading index.vue inside another v-container?

Comment: Yes, removing the container helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from a comment on the question it turns out that Nuxt has a default.vue and all the other components are mounted in that component at the  tag. That tag was wrapped inside a container like:

```
<v-content>
  <v-container>
    <nuxt/>
  </v-container>
</v-content>
```

Removing the container removed the padding

```
<v-content>
    <nuxt/>
</v-content>
```